# display: inline-table equivalent crossbrower

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

I have 2 radiobutton inside a `<td>` attribute in a HTML table. They both have a `<label>` tag.
As we know, the table tag doesnt have the attribute width, and I'm trying to find a crossbrowser solution to set a space between the labels of each radiobutton.

I have this code:

```
<td class="changeUnitsSetLabelWidth">
  <?php echo $form->radio("changeUnitsMode",UnitsTabComponent::SET_ALL_METRIC)->set("id","changeUnitsMode_metric") . $form->label("changeUnitsMode", "Metric")->set("for","changeUnitsMode_metric");
        echo $form->radio("changeUnitsMode", UnitsTabComponent::SET_ALL_IMPERIAL)->set("id","changeUnitsMode_imperial") . $form->label("changeUnitsMode", "Imperial")->set("for","changeUnitsMode_imperial");
  ?>
</td>
```

and I added the following line in my CSS:

```
.changeUnitsSetLabelWidth label{ display: inline-table; width: 80px;}
```

After searching on the internet, I found it doesnt work for IE7 (what a news!?!) so I'd like you to help me to find another way to do this display: inline-table, in a way I can set the width in the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was changing it all and, instead of using inside a `<td>` attribute, I used it in a `<div> <span>` attribute and it worked well. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

using `display:inline-table` does not make any sense here. Just set `display:inline-block` and set a width and a margin for the space between and you should be fine.

The IE7 hack for behaving like inline-block is:

```
 zoom: 1;
 *display: inline;
```

Comment: this is why I wanted another solution @Christoph, because it had no sense (but it worked). And the inline-block didn't solve my problem.. I removed it from the table and I created a new <div> to manage it and now it works well, but thanks anyway!

Comment: in my case `*display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top;` to keep all elements top aligned

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.changeUnitsSetLabelWidth input,
.changeUnitsSetLabelWidth label {
    float: left;
}
.changeUnitsSetLabelWidth label {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: as a matter fact, instead of using a table, I changed it and put inside a <div> and <span> and I have no more this problem, but thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by

```
.my-class{
    *display: inline; 
    zoom: 1; 
    vertical-align: top;` 
}
```

It kept all elements top aligned.